# Can I use Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService in Visual Studio Unit Test (class library) project?

Tags: unit-testing, dependency-injection, xamarin, xamarin.forms, vs-unit-testing-framework

I am building a mobile application using Xamarin Forms and taking advantage of MVVM through Xamarin Forms Labs plugin.  I have my solution set up as follows:

- iOS project
- UI Portable Class Library project (Views/Xaml only)
- Core Portable Class Library project (ViewsModels/Models/everything else)
- Testing Class Library project

I have successfully added the testing project with a reference to both Xamarin Forms and Xamarin Forms Labs, and can run tests instantiating the ViewModels.  However as I am using Xamarin Forms Dependency Service for cross platform functionality and I thought I could use it as well in the Testing library to inject dummy implementations for those platform specific calls.  This way I could more fully test the View Models and everything else.

However in the following code:

```
    [TestMethod()]
    public void TestingDependencyInjection()
    {
        string strInfo = Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Get<Interfaces.ITestingInterface>().GetInformation();
        Assert.IsFalse(string.IsNullOrEmpty(strInfo));
    }
```

There is an InvalidOperationException thrown from Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll with the following information: "You MUST call Xamarin.Forms.Init(); prior to using it."

But in the testing project "Init" is not a member of Forms!

I suppose I could use some other injection service on top of the one that already is in Xamarin Forms but I was hoping not to do that.

Anyone else tried to do this?

Comment: IMHO You should really create an UserVoice request for this one.
http://xamarin.uservoice.com/forums/258559-xamarin-forms-suggestions

Comment: I have followed your suggestion.  Vote at following link: http://xamarin.uservoice.com/forums/258559-xamarin-forms-suggestions/suggestions/6489344-make-xamarin-forms-dependencyservice-compatible-wi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to assign a class that implements IPlatformServices to Device.PlatformServices static property. Now, that is tricky because both IPlatformServices interface and Device.PlatformServices are internal. But it is doable.

Name your unittest assembly as "Xamarin.Forms.Core.UnitTests" because internals are visible to assembly named like that (among few other names).

Implement fake PlatformServices, i.e.:

```
public class PlatformServicesMock: IPlatformServices
{
    void IPlatformServices.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(Action action)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    ITimer IPlatformServices.CreateTimer(Action<object> callback)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    ITimer IPlatformServices.CreateTimer(Action<object> callback, object state, int dueTime, int period)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    ITimer IPlatformServices.CreateTimer(Action<object> callback, object state, long dueTime, long period)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    ITimer IPlatformServices.CreateTimer(Action<object> callback, object state, TimeSpan dueTime, TimeSpan period)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    ITimer IPlatformServices.CreateTimer(Action<object> callback, object state, uint dueTime, uint period)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    Assembly[] IPlatformServices.GetAssemblies()
    {
        return new Assembly[0];
    }
    Task<Stream> IPlatformServices.GetStreamAsync(Uri uri, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    IIsolatedStorageFile IPlatformServices.GetUserStoreForApplication()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    void IPlatformServices.OpenUriAction(Uri uri)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    void IPlatformServices.StartTimer(TimeSpan interval, Func<bool> callback)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    bool IPlatformServices.IsInvokeRequired
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Take note that I am not returning any assembly in GetAssembly block (there assemblies are analyzed for types that implements the interfaces). Feel free to return an array of assemblies you need.

Assign an instance of PlatformServicesMock to Device.PlatformServices:

```
var platformServicesProperty = typeof(Device).GetProperty("PlatformServices", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        platformServicesProperty.SetValue(null, new PlatformServicesMock());
```

That's a dirty solution but it should work nevertheless. Also note that Visual Studio would probably draw a lot of squiggle lines indicating errors (internal not visible) but would compile just fine.

HTH

Comment: THANKS! That worked.  Never would've figured this out, completely non intuitive.

Comment: It seems it's now a bit easier; the IPlatformServices interface is public now: http://brianlagunas.com/mocking-and-unit-testing-the-xamarin-forms-application-class/

Comment: And I just found this, which also looks promising: http://jonathanpeppers.com/Blog/mocking-xamarin-forms